# Replacing all consecutive "\r\n or \n"s with one single <br>

Tags: java, html, regex, string

Currently I am showing messages that I get from DB using only these two replacements:

```
text = text.replace("\r\n", "<br />");
text = text.replace("\n", "<br />");
```

but the problem is if there are many consecutive "\n"s I will have lots of 
s or white spaces, I just want to make them all one. So what is your suggestion? Is there a quick replace method to make all consecutive \n\n\n\n\n\n\n only one just one br?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use quantifier `+` to denote 1 or more..
Also, `*` means 0 or more..

```
text = text.replaceAll("\n+", "<br />");

text = text.replaceAll("[\n\r]+", "<br />");
```

Comment: Thanks and if its \r\n or \n it will be text = text.replace("\n+|\n\r+", "<br />"); ?

Comment: @NullUserException.. Why?? And which one first or second??

Comment: @RohitJain The second, but you fixed it.

Comment: @NullUserException.. Now its better.. I used character class to denote `\n` or `\r`..

Comment: `replace` doesn't accept regular expressions, `replaceAll` does.

Comment: @RohitJain Your second line makes the first one redundant.

Comment: @NullUserException.. Yeah.. Because it covers both.. Probably I would quote that..

Comment: You probably meant `(\r\n)+`; `(\n+\r+)` (which in this case doesn't need the parens), matches a string of `\n` characters followed by a string of `\r`s. `(\n|\r)+` behaves like the third regex, only less efficiently.

Comment: @NullUserException Edited code.. That works.. Actually 2nd and 3rd were same... So, removed the 2nd..

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple `\r\n` or `\n` with other content in between, you may also use

```
text.replaceAll("(\r\n)+", "<br />")
    .replaceAll("\n+", "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
text = text.replace("(\r\n)+", "<br />");
text = text.replace("\n+", "<br />");
```

The `+` means "one or more" of the preceding match.